# What is the purpose of using your initials instead of your full name in oral presentations and when is it appropriate

Tags: etiquette, presentation, physics

I noticed during some conference talks that some presenters use their initials rather than their full names on some presentationn slides. Specifically I noticed this when they show name-labeled photos of their teams or have slides where they highlight key contributors to a broader scientific field.

I'm not sure whether this is a cultural quirk (I did't catch any pattern regarding nationality), a means to draw attention towards your research team (it seems to be more common for team leaders and professors) or just a boastful way of understatement (since everybody knows who "X.X." is).

Additionally, is  doing this appropriate and/or advisable for an (under)grad student and if so, in what context?

Comment: @DanRomik The link in your comment no longer works.

Answer (score 6):

The convention in mathematics is to use your last initial during talks when citing your own work. Probably it seems a little vainglorious as well as unnecessary to write out your entire name. There's no reason undergraduate/graduate students shouldn't participate in the same conventions as more experienced researchers.

Comment: Right, either the last initial or sometimes the last initial followed by a horizontal line, e.g. (Theorem (C----)).  To me the most honest explanation of this is that it *is* a cultural quirk.  I follow this practice myself, as do most of my colleagues, but it is hard to argue objectively that this is done out of humility.  I get for instance a small whiff of the Jewish practice of unwillingness to write out the full name of God, and the implications of this association are not very humble!  Anyway, we do it because others around us do it is the simplest and most correct explanation, I think.

Comment: On the other hand, doing this *when identifying photos* is something that I have not seen before, so maybe that comes from a different part of academic culture.  But the explanation that I gave in my previous comment presumably applies to this case as well: they are doing it because others around them are doing it.

Comment: But when it occasionally happens that someone *does* write out their full name, isn't there a small voice in your head saying, "What a jerk"?

Comment: Close, but not quite.  The small voice says: "Alert -- this person is not doing the culturally acceptable thing."  Whether I think this makes them a jerk depends on lots of other things.  It might make me think for instance that this person has not given or seen many math talks....

Comment: ...And even if I did think that...so what?  It would still be an instance of cultural programming rather than cosmic truth.  Consider for instance the case of "Tai's model" (google it if necessary): among the things that M.M. Tai got called out for was actually herself using that phrase.  In her response, Tai makes clear that using the same language to describe her model as those around her are using is simple and logical.  I think she has a good point there.

Comment: @Pete I agree with you that it's strictly cultural! My point was just that the motivation for the convention was "humility," whether or not that's actually the case.

Comment: The speaker's name is commonly abbreviated only in places like "Theorem (G.)". If the name has gotten attached to some mathematical object like a ring, a function or even a Named Theorem ("Grinberg's Theorem" as opposed to "Theorem (Grinberg 2016)"), then I don't usually see it abbreviated.

Comment: Echoing others' remarks, this practice is absolutely standard in math, although one could certainly construe it as a goofy sort of false modesty. When I see people not conform, I don't so much think they're truly egotists (any more than the rest of us) but that they're not aware of the convention (in the U.S., Canada, and perhaps Western Europe).

Comment: @darijgrinberg On the other hand, I also recall seeing speakers attempt with varying success to not use their own name for theorems or objects named after them (by varying success, I mean in terms of how natural it seemed).

Comment: @PeteL.Clark Tai got called out for naming it Tai's model in the very paper in which it was "introduced". She explained this by claiming that she had actually named it after one of her parents (unfortunately, I can't seem to find this last part anywhere now. It was a reply to some comments on the paper).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft people were led to think Tai named Tai's model after her parents due to what she wrote in the acknowledgments section at the end of her paper ("I would like to dedidcate Tai's model to my late parents...").  It's not clear that those words mean she was naming it after them. In her response to the follow-up letters reacting to that paper, she said that her colleagues started calling it the technique "Tai's model". Certainly the colleagues were not thinking of Tai's parents, so I think the idea that she named it after her parents is due to a misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

1. Long Names: individuals with long names
2. Gender-Neutral Names: J. Doe. Vs. John/Jane Doe. Some fields are still ambivalent towards gender equality, and as a result using initials anonymize the author's gender.
3. Marriage or Legal Name Change: Sometimes people hyphenate their last names when they get married.
4. Space Limitation: on some slides with many individuals, using initials can save space.